# I want Typeorm to return undefined rather than an error

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, nest

Hi I want to check if a user is in the database already.

I use Typeorm and Postgres.

I use Typeorm to check if the user is in my DB if not so that's ok and I want the variable to be null/undefined. The issue is that it stops my server with a 400 error code and the process stops.

```
const isInDb = await this.clientDb.findOne({ email });
```

error when not found
response: {
statusCode: 400,
message: 'cannot update DB, this request is invalid',
error: 'Bad Request'
},

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the TypeORM API, but if you want to replace unwanted rejections, you could always wrap the returned promise:

```
function hideRejection<T>(promise: Promise<T>, rejectValue: T = undefined): Promise<T> {
  return promise.catch(() => rejectValue)
}
```

Then use it like:

```
const isInDb = await hideRejection(this.clientDb.findOne({ email }));
```

Comment: If the response will be positive the above would return the rejected response each time no?

Comment: @Tomer give it a try! If the promise is a success, you still get the resolved value. It's equivalent to this, if the promise resolves: `await Promise.resolve("resolved").catch(() => "caught")`

Comment: I tried but Postgres fails with the above I had to use getCount and then if x>0 use the initial function to find the user.

Answer (score 0):

I just used getcount() query builder to check how many times the row exists. This doesn't throw an error.